# Chrome ext tabs :Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: google-chrome-extension, communication

i try to connect to just created new tab , my end mission is to update html widget on all open tabs
any way each time i try to connect to tabs via id i fail with error . im using Version 23.0.1271.64 m

```
var channelTabs = [];
  function isInclude(arr,obj) {
    return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
}
    chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {

      // add tab when opened
     if (channelTabs.indexOf(tab.id) == -1) {
        channelTabs.push(tab.id);
     }

    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win)
    {
        // get an array of the tabs in the window
        chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(win.id, function(tabs)
        {
            for (i in tabs) // loop over the tabs
            {
                // if the tab is not the selected one
                if(isInclude(channelTabs,tabs[i].id))
                {
                    if(/^(https?|file):/.test(tabs[i].url))
                    {
                        console.log('Debug Background sending update to open tab id:'+tabs[i].id);
                        var port = chrome.tabs.connect(tabs[i].id,{name: "content_tab_request"});
                        port.postMessage({resp: "tab_update",data:"some string song1"});
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    });


    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo,tab) {
    // Example: allow http:, https: and file:
    if (/^(https?|file):/.test(tab.url)) {
            console.log('Debug Background sending onUpdated to open tab id:'+tabId);
            var port = chrome.tabs.connect(tabId,{name: "content_tab_request"});
            port.postMessage({resp: "tab_update",data:"some string song1"});
    }
    });


 });
```

but each time it try to chrome.tabs.connect it gives me :

```
Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. miscellaneous_bindings:235
chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect miscellaneous_bindings:235
chrome.Event.dispatch_ event_bindings:371
dispatchArgs event_bindings:249
chromeHidden.Event.dispatchEvent
```

and the content script :

```
// Register this tab to the background script
  var port = chrome.extension.connect({name: "content_request"});
  port.postMessage({req: "Hello"});

  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {

    if (msg.resp == "World")
    {      
      port.postMessage({answer: "good"});
    }
    else if(msg.answer == "bye")
    {
         console.log('Debug contentscript.js reciving answer from background msg.answer:'+msg.answer);
    }
    else
    {
         console.log('Debug contentscript.js reciving answer from background is wrong:'+msg);
    }

    if(port.name == "content_tab_request")
    {
        console.log('Debug contentscript.js reciving request from background Tab function:'+msg);
        if(msg.resp=="tab_update ")
        {
            var data_recive = msg.data;
            console.log('Debug contentscript.js reciving request data from background Tab to update page data_recive:'+data_recive);

        }
    }
  });
```

json file :

```
{
   "background": {
      "page": "background.html" 
   },
   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],       
      "js": ["contentscript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": true
    }
   ],
   "web_accessible_resources": [
    "script_inpage.js"
   ],
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon19.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_title": "Simple test"
   },
   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; media-src *; object-src 'self'",
   "description": "Simple test.",
   "icons": {
      "128": "icon128.png",
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "32": "icon32.png",
      "48": "icon48.png"
   },

   "manifest_version": 2,
   "minimum_chrome_version": "20",
   "name": "Simple test",
   "permissions": [ 
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "http://*/",
        "<all_urls>",
        "tabs"
   ],

   "version": "2.6"
}
```

by the way connection from content script to background working just fine !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it seems you are trying to synchronize asynchronous events, after simplification of your code i got it running with modifications and achieved your functional requirement of `posting message to all tabs when a new tab is created`.

```
Output:
```

I was able to see this message on all tabs

[image]

***manifest.json***

```
{
"name":"Sample communication from content to background",
"description":"This is a sample for Simulating communication from content to background",
"manifest_version":2,
"version":"2",
"background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"],
      "run_at":"document_start"
    }
  ]
}
```

***"background.js"***

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
     chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win){
        chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(win.id, function(tabs){
            for (i=0;i<tabs.length;i++){
                console.log(tabs[i]);
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id,{name: "content_tab_request"});
            }
        });
    });
});
```

***"myscript.js"***

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    console.log("Message Recieved   "+ msg); 
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , well in the background script it doesn't give any error , but in the content script , it seams the onMessage doesn't triggered , also why i can't use persistent  connection with port object ?

Comment: @user63898: You can use persistent connection but you should ensure reciever exists before you `postMessage()` which is missing in your scenario so i have suggested `sendMessage()` API

Comment: how can i ensure this ? i did check if tab exist. 
also i testing and i see the tab (:

Comment: ok i updated with my json file , mybe there is problem init ? 
i just can't get any massage from the backgound to the content script

Comment: @user63898: I believe you are not sending an acknowledgement back to background.js from tabs in this case working with `sendMessage()` will solve your problem; to avoid `could not connect error` for long lived connections for background - > tabs scenario is to wait until new tab is completely loaded and ready with content script injected with port listener, chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener do not guarantee the new tab is completely loaded

Answer (score 0):

Also some chrome extentions may produce this error. i had this problem and the problem was [Aside](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hkhbmdeeajbgkdpaiencghlmbgbkpdaa) extention (for saving articles to Pocket).
the error was:

> Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. miscellaneous_bindings:235
>   chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect